# Getting certificate chain to a private root

Tags: c++, winapi, certificate, x509, cryptoapi

I'm trying to verify that the certificate from a signature chains back to a particular root certificate, which is *not* trusted by Windows (it's a private certificate for the app).

My current attempt to do this involves creating a chaining engine which only trusts the specific certificate I want as the root, so that no other chains can be generated.

```
HCERTSTORE hPrivateRootStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME, dwEncoding,
    NULL, CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG,
    _T("C:\\Test\\PrivateRoot.cer"));
CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG config;
memset(&config, 0, sizeof(config));
config.cbSize = sizeof(config);
config.hRestrictedTrust = hPrivateRootStore;
config.dwFlags = CERT_CHAIN_CACHE_ONLY_URL_RETRIEVAL | CERT_CHAIN_ENABLE_SHARE_STORE;
HCERTCHAINENGINE hEngine;
CertCreateCertificateChainEngine(&config, &hEngine);
CERT_CHAIN_PARA params;
memset(&params, 0, sizeof(params));
params.cbSize = sizeof(params);
PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT chains = NULL;
if (CertGetCertificateChain(hEngine, pCertContext, NULL, hStore, &params,
    0, NULL, &chains))
   ...
```

(error checking omitted for clarity; `pCertContext` and `hStore` came from `CryptQueryObject` extracting the signature and related certificates from a signed binary file.)

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work; despite using a custom chaining engine it still seems to be searching the OS store, and either doesn't find a chain or finds one to a different root (which is trusted by the OS).  I can only get the chain I want by adding my private root certificate to the OS trusted store.

I've also tried setting `config.hRestrictedOther` to an empty memory store, since the docs suggest that having `hRestrictedTrust` non-NULL will bring in the system stores again, but that doesn't make any difference.

Is there something I'm missing, or a better way to do this?

**Edit**: just to give a bit more context, I'm trying to do something similar to the driver signing certificates, where the signing certificate chains back to two different roots: one standard CA root trusted by the OS and one internal root (which in drivers is also trusted by the OS but in my case will only be trusted by my app).  The cross occurs somewhere mid-way up the "main" chain; there could potentially be a number of different files all signed with different "real" CAs but still chained back to my internal certificate.

Comment: After some more investigation, I've discovered the `hExclusiveRoot` member added to `CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG` in Win7. I think the associated description makes it clear that `CertCreateCertificateChainEngine` doesn't provide any mechanism to ignore the system stores in older versions (which makes me wonder what the heck it's actually for, but that's a separate issue). So, new question: is there some other way to enumerate possible chains back to my desired root? Something compatible with `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` would be nice, although I can probably live without it if need be.

Comment: What what format is the certificate file you are trying to analyze?

Comment: The subject is an Authenticode-signed binary, the desired root is a .cer compiled into the app and loaded as a `PCCERT_CONTEXT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I've found a half-baked workaround now; it's a little ugly but it does kinda work.  I got the basic idea from [Chromium's test suite](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/base/test_root_certs_win.cc?view=markup&pathrev=69351); it involves installing a hook into Crypt32 such that when it tries to open the system stores to build the chain it gets my custom store instead, containing only my desired certificate.</strike>

<strike>The good is that this seems to force `CertGetCertificateChain` to go "past" the real CA certificate and chain all the way to my custom certificate, instead of stopping at the CA certificate (which is what it usually does when that is trusted).</strike>

<strike>The bad is that it doesn't seem to stop it from building chains to and trusting any other CA certificate.  I can work around that by explicitly verifying that the root of the chain is the certificate I wanted, but it's less than ideal, and I'm not sure if there are situations which will trip it up.</strike>

<strike>Still looking for any better solutions; I'm definitely getting the impression that I'm taking the wrong path somewhere.</strike>

Ok, new plan.  I'm now just walking the chain manually (since I know that all of the certificates I care about will be in the `hStore` extracted from the signed .exe), with basic structure like this:

- Use `WinVerifyTrust` to do basic "is it not tampered" authentication.
- Use `CryptQueryObject` to obtain certificate store `hStore` from the .exe
- Use `CryptMsgGetParam` and `CertFindCertificateInStore` to find the signing certificate from `hStore`.
- Starting from the signing certificate, use `CertFindCertificateInStore` with `CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_NAME` in a loop to find the potential issuer certificates; keep walking back until I hit a self-signed certificate or find my desired root (checking for a match via `CertComparePublicKeyInfo`).
- Abandon a particular branch if `CertVerifySubjectCertificateContext` says that the signatures don't match.

Seems cleaner than the previous approaches I was trying.  Thoughts/comments/alternatives?

(Something which in some ways does seem to make more sense would be to add an additional custom countersignature [similar to the timestamping] instead of trying to chain certificates like this, but I can't find any information on doing that, or what the pros/cons are.)